# Windows 8 Logon Screen Error

Tags: windows-8, bios, login

I was messing around, and my windows 8 logon screen is now black/blank. If I could get my computer to safe mode, I could fix it, but I can't access the windows 8 advanced boot options since I can't restart and shift click the computer. Does anyone know a solution?

Please Help!

Comment: Someone please help!

Comment: Boot from the WIn8 DVD and select the advanced options. If you don't have a DVD, download the 90 day Enterprise Eval Edition to get a DVD.

Comment: You can also try bashing Shift+F8 while booting up, but with Win8 it's unlikely you'll be able to do it fast enough. Best to use an install/recovery DVD as mentioned above.